# How do I convert a string of decimal numbers into ASCII?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a string that reads as:

54565550445154544949445056555748445254555650445350485354445350535053445349565453445053564955445453535153445552494844524650504450485049474949475148445048585558501310⸮

How do I transform it to read as:

6872,36611,28790,46782,52056,52525,51865,25817,65535,7410,4.22,2021/11/30,20:7:2

?

Comment: Please clarify, why the second string would be the result of transforming the first string. How are they related exactly?

Comment: One major problem is that ASCII is the values `0` to `127`, it's one to three digits. How do you know that `5456` should be just `54` and `56`, not `5`, `4`, `5` and `6` as separate numbers? Or `5` and `45` and `6`?

Comment: Given the examples provided it _looks_ like the OP is assuming each ASCII code is two base ten digits.

Comment: If true, it's a matter of iterating over the string two characters at a time, turning those two characters into an int, casting that int to a char, and then storing it elsewhere.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Try to write down - as specific as possible - how the input is structured, how it should be interpreted and how the input is actually related to the output. Once you know this, it shouldn't be to hard to figure out an algorithm (with pen and paper) to transform input to output. And after that coding it in C++ should be the easiest part.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your input is a series of 2-byte decimal numbers. Each pair represents an ascii char.  That's an unusual way to encode data.  If the input stream had any ascii char with an ordinal value over 99, it couldn't be encoded.

A quick decode loop could look like the following. Making use of `strtol` to convert each pair of numbers back to an integer.

```
std::string s = "54565550445154544949445056555748445254555650445350485354445350535053445349565453445053564955445453535153445552494844524650504450485049474949475148445048585558501310";
std::string result;

size_t pairs = s.length() / 2;

for (size_t i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
{
    char tmp[3] = { s[i*2], s[i*2 + 1], '\0' };

    char c = (unsigned char)(strtoul(tmp, nullptr, 10));

    result += c;
}
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Prints out the following:

```
6872,36611,28790,46782,52056,52525,51865,25817,65535,7410,4.22,2021/11/30,20:7:2
```

Comment: Rather than divide the length in half, why not simply increment `i` by `2`?

Comment: @Chris - Consider the possibility of an odd-length string.

Comment: It would simply ignore the last character in the encoded string.  `for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2) { ... }`. As your loop does.

Comment: @Chris - perhaps you could write up an answer that deals with that boundary case even more cleanly.  I might even upvote it myself.

Comment: It's a pretty trivial modification of your answer, without much novel to offer.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to make small functions to help you solve your problem step by step.
So there is an (inline) function to convert two characters back to one,
and another one to convert a whole input string.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

inline char convert(const char c1, const char c2)
{
    return ((c1 - '0') * 10) + (c2 - '0');
}

std::string convert(const std::string& string)
{
    assert((string.size() & 1) == 0); // "input string must have an even length"
    std::stringstream output; 

    for(std::size_t pos=0ul; pos < string.length(); pos += 2)
    {
        // I prefer this over using std::string +=
        output << convert(string[pos], string[pos+1]);
    }

    return output.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string input{ "54565550445154544949445056555748445254555650445350485354445350535053445349565453445053564955445453535153445552494844524650504450485049474949475148445048585558501310" };
    auto output = convert(input);
    std::cout << output;
    return 0;
}
```